# Interfaces not properly represent in proxy objects

Tags: c#, wcf, service-reference

Using many [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141093/collection-interfaces-and-wcf) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729145/serializing-interface-in-wcf) [fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835505/wcf-interface-and-methods) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192048/using-interfaces-with-wcf) on this website, I have gotten my WCF service to properly serialize and deserialize concrete objects of interface types across the wire.  Unfortunately, why seems to be lacking to me is client support.

A user has retrieved the meta-data from my service and is using that to auto-generate a service reference in visual studio 2012 with "add service reference".  They are complaining that in their reference.cs (and thus in their auto-fill tool-tips), interfaces aren't coming across and are replaced by object.

For example, in my service interface code file:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ConcreteObject))]
...
[OperationContract]
bool WorkMethod(IMyInterface argument1);
...
```

but what they see is:

```
...
[OperationContract]
bool WorkMethod(object argument1);
...
```

As stated above, my client library works fine because I understand "object" really means "IMyInterface".  But this is unclear to another client.  How do you force the generated proxy objects to include interfaces, and properly represent the request type?

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: Example interface, as per request.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    bool DoWork(int i);

    string SomeProperty { get; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(IMyInterface))]
public class ConcreteObject : IMyInterface
{
    //Working implementation here.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Post an example of your IMyInterface.  You may need to attribute it with a DataContractAttribute.

Comment: DataContract is only available for objects, structs, and enums.  Is there another attribute that I don't know about that achieves this?

Comment: Doesn't your ConcreteObject need to implement the interface? `public class ConcreteObject : IMyInterface `

Comment: right.  I think you will have to provide a concrete type. see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720730/wcf-and-interfaces-on-data-contracts

Comment: Yes Bensonius, it does.  Forgot to add it in this pared down example.  Fixed ;)

Comment: You cannot use an interface as a parameter or return type in an operation. It cannot be represented in WSDL. You will need to use a concrete type.